# MarketingCloud SDK Crash When Migrating to Android 12 - Xamarin Android

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I am currently working on a Xamarin Android project with binding v6.x.That needs to be migrated to Android 12. When I tried migrating, I got the following crash:

**com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a**
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.biloholdings.mywinndixie.qa: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

**Stack traces**

```
android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags PendingIntent.java:382
android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser PendingIntent.java:673
android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast PendingIntent.java:660
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.c
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.analytics.c.b$2.a
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d.a.run
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637
java.lang.Thread.run Thread.java:1012
```

Is anybody facing issue with binding v8.x?

Answer (score 1):

Android 12 support is included in v7.4.3 or greater of the SDKs. A binding for a version earlier than that will not work, and I'm sure you're aware, Xamarin is not officially supported.